# Add/remove class from two different states

Tags: javascript, angular

I have two boolean states that are enabled differently. However, one state adds a class to a div, while the other should remove it. I am however unsure how this is done ?

For example, I was first trying to do something like this:

```
<div [ngClass]="{'is-active' : state1, 'is-removed' : state2}"></div>
```

However, since `is-active` and `is-removed` have the same properties, i.e. one should cancel the other, this doesn't really work as intended since they are both added to the div if both states are true.

In principle, the default state of the div (`is-active` or `is-removed` is not added) is what `is-removed` is supposed to be doing (but then isn't).

So how do I remove `is-active` even though `state1` is still true, but `state2` is also true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add additional condition to 'is-active' class enabling:

```
<div [ngClass]="{'is-active' : !state2 && state1, 'is-removed' : state2}"></div>
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.